# How to retrieve rails recaptcha gem error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, recaptcha

How do I get the error returned by

```
verify_recaptcha
```

on the ruby gem https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha

I need to know if it failed because it expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call the method with:

```
if verify_recaptcha(model: @model, attribute: :your_attribute) && @model.save
  redirect_to model_path(@model), notice: t('saved')
else
  flash[:alert] = t('error')
  render :show, status: 422
end
```

The error will be set on

```
model.errors[:your_attribute]
```

You can see the explanation of each option here:
https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha#verify_recaptcha